# Why does my website return 2 space after retrieve in vuejs axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

Im new in vuejs, currently learning how to retrieve all data.

[image]

The image above shows that the return was empty but still have 2 row of spacing, I dont know why.

Below are the codes on my checker.vue

```
<template>
<div id="app">  

  <button @click="loadAll()">Load ALL</button>
      <li v-for="(warranty, index) in warrantys" :key="index">
         {{warranty.id}} -{{warranty.warranty_code}} - {{warranty.receipt}} - {{warranty.warranty_status}}
      </li> </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            warrantys:[

            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
      loadAll(){
        this.axios({ 
          method: 'get',
          url: 'http://www.example.com/process.php?action=read',
        }).then((response) => {
            this.warrantys = response.data;
        });  
      },
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, I've tried to console log this.warranty. It returns the correct data. So I suspect that the problem was binding the data to it right?

Also I've to mentioned here is that im using CLI to create this project.

Pleaseee helppppp
[image: The console]

Comment: Can you show result of `console.log(response.data)` ?

Comment: Dear Bình Trương, I've updated the code.

Comment: Could you try `this.warrantys = response.data.$warrantys`

Comment: Wow, it works. How come it return $warrantys instead